# Background position from right in percentage

Tags: css, position, background-image, background-position

Is there a way to display a `background image` from right in percents? In pixels the values working well, but not in percents!
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hirdbluebird/yh04d0hs/)

html:`<div></div>`

css:

```
div {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Arrow-PNG-Pic.png');
  background-size: auto 90%;
  background-position: right 20% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. Can you specific the browser?

Comment: Did you take into account that those percentages are based on the actual size the image displays in (regarding your `background-size: auto 90%`) …?

Answer (score 1):

Your background is too big. It's bigger than 100%. That gives you unpredictable result! Here you can see you code with smaller size of png, working as expected!

```
div {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Arrow-PNG-Pic.png');
  background-size: auto 10%;
  background-position: right 10% center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zn2ujy4b/

Comment: Background image should have possibility to overflow by x axis in left side. When I start to scale image width to 90% and over, `background-position` percentage working as not expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an error. You are saying:

```
background-position: right 20% center;
```

It should be `X% Y%`:

```
div {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: url('http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Arrow-PNG-Pic.png');
  background-size: auto 20%;
  background-position: 90% 50% ;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7crmqpf/)

Comment: They are referring to the “extended” syntax for specifying _edge offsets values_, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-position